# “Boot error” when booting YUMI USB flash drive

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, bootloader

I created my [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) USB flash drive some time ago. I’ve used this drive to boot various PC’s successfully (so other situation than in [an existing question](https://superuser.com/q/473358/84807)).

However, when I tried to boot my laptop using the flash drive today, I got a single message:

```
Boot error
```

I was then able to reboot the computer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.

I’ve been also using the same drive to transfer data since a YUMI drive is just a bootable FAT32 drive. So I’m not sure it hasn’t got unbootable somehow. In the Disk Management in Windows 7, the drive is shown as `Healthy (Active, Primary Partition)`.

I tried to add another Linux distro to the drive using YUMI-2.0.5.6.exe on Windows 7 (the same machine I had used to create the drive) and was hoping it could repair the bootloader but the next boot was the same. The first log message of the installer was `Good Syslinux exists`, so it most likely did not touch the bootloader.

Is there any way to repair the bootloader of existing YUMI drive? I haven’t found any corresponding option in the install window.

[image: install window screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to force YUMI to reinstall the bootloader by renaming the following files in the `multiboot` folder:

- libcom32.c32
- ldlinux.sys (hidden by default)

Then YUMI reinstalled bootloader when installing another ISO using its wizard. The file `ldlinux.sys` was recreated but `libcom32.c32` not, so I had to rename it back. Then I was able to boot my YUMI drive again!

The described behavior is based on the following [YUMI source code](https://github.com/richi235/YUMI/blob/master/YUMI.nsi#L1023):

```
${IfNot} ${FileExists} "$BootDir\multiboot\libcom32.c32" 
${AndIf} ${FileExists} "$BootDir\multiboot\ldlinux.sys"
MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK $(WarningSyslinuxOLD)
Quit
${EndIf}

IfFileExists "$BootDir\multiboot\libcom32.c32" SkipSyslinux CreateSyslinux ; checking for newer syslinux
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and followed your advice, except that I didn't have to rename ldlinux.sys and install a new ISO.

I had an ldlinux.sys backed up, and I just deleted the same on the USB drive, and copied my backed-up ldlinux.sys into the YUMI drive.

And it worked.